# SwiftUI error: Generic parameter 'Label' could not be inferred Explicitly specify the generic arguments to fix this issue `

Tags: swiftui

I can't find the issue for this error. I don't think the compiler is giving a meaningful error message.

Why `self.book.map {}` does not work here?

```
var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(cards) { card in
            if (!self.showMarkedOnly || card.marked) {
                ZStack() {
                    CardView(card: card).frame(maxWidth: 400)
                        .contextMenu() {
                            if self.editMode {
                                Button(action: {}) { HStack { Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil"); Text("Edit") } }
                                Button(action: {}) { HStack { Image(systemName: "trash"); Text("Delete") } }
                                // self.book.map { Button(action: { self.onRemoveCard(card, fromBook: $0) }) { HStack { Image(systemName: "folder.badge.minus"); Text("Remove from current Book") } } } // ERROR happens here
                                if self.book != nil {
                                    Button(action: { self.onRemoveCard(card, fromBook: self.book!) }) { HStack { Image(systemName: "folder.badge.minus"); Text("Remove from current Book") } }
                                } // <------- this works!!! but I prefer to not use "self.book!"
                            } else {} }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the actual error in the title? That would help show your question with an appropriate title in the feed

Comment: if `book.map` is what I think about then it generates sequence and that's not a `View`, that would expected in `MenuItems` for `ContextMenu`

Comment: @Honey, I have already said that the error showing is nothing to do with the actual error, it's Swiftui complier issue.

Comment: @Asperi, book is an optional value. map has two methods, one for array, one for optional value.

the following two code should be the same, but error occured using the first one:
`self.book.map { Button(action: { self.onRemoveCard(card, fromBook: $0) }) { HStack { Image(systemName: "folder.badge.minus"); Text("Remove from current Book") } } } `
`if self.book != nil {
    Button(action: { self.onRemoveCard(card, fromBook: self.book!) }) { HStack { Image(systemName: "folder.badge.minus"); Text("Remove from current Book") } }
}`

Comment: @Honey, you right! error shows:
`Generic parameter 'Label' could not be inferred`
`Explicitly specify the generic arguments to fix this issue`

Comment: I edited the question. The title should not be 'why isn't this working' If that was the case then we'd have 500000 questions all asking different questions with different titles. Similar title questions also helps to find duplicate questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case of nesting closures interfering with $0. Try this:

```
self.book.map { book in Button(action: { self.onRemoveCard(card, fromBook: book) }) { ... }
```